# The transmitted signal of DPSK

Tags: homework, modulation, bandpass

I am very confused about how to get the transmit sequence of the DPSK signal.

In my lecture notes, teacher give as the following example.

```
Assume the following rule is apply

"no change" of sign for information 1
"change" of sign for information 0

if the data sequence is "0000 1010 1110 0011"
then the transmitted sequence is "+ -+-+ +--+ +++- +---"

if the data sequence is "1101 0000 0111"
then the transmitted sequence is "- --++ -+-+ ----"
```

I cannot understand why the data sequence is 0000 and the transmit sequence is `-+-+` instead of `++++`? and When should I use `+` or `-` in the transmitted sequence?

Comment: Because the signal changes sign when the data is a 0.  The key is that it doesn't matter what the signal starts as (+ or -), what matters is how it changes.